# Nvidia OpenCL hangs on blocking buffer access

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I have an OpenCL program that copies a bunch of values to an input buffer, processes these values, and copies the results back.

```
// map input data buffer, has CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR
cl_float* data = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, data_buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, data_size, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// set input values
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    data[i] = values[i];

// unmap input buffer
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, data_buffer, data, 0, NULL, NULL);

// run kernels
...

// map results buffer, has CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR
cl_float* results = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, results_buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, results_size, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// processing
...

// unmap results buffer
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, results_buffer, results, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

(In the real code, I check for errors etc.)

This works great on AMD and Intel architectures (both CPU and GPU). On Nvidia GPUs, the code is incredibly slow. A program that takes normally takes 10 seconds to run (5 seconds host, 5 seconds device) will run for more than two and a half minutes on Nvidia cards.

However, I have found that this is not a straightforward optimisation problem or zero-copy speed difference. Using a profiler, I see that the host time of the program is 5 seconds, as in the normal case. And using OpenCL profiling events, I see that the device time is also 5 seconds, as in the normal case!

So I used the [poor mans' profiler](http://poormansprofiler.org) trick to figure out where the program spends its time on Nvidia GPUs. And it shows that the program just waits idly on both of the `clEnqueueMapBuffer` calls. I find this especially incomprehensible on the first instance, as the queue is empty at that point.

I repeat, I have profiled every map/unmap and kernel invocation, and the extra time does not show up there, so it's not spent on the device, and neither on the host. I can see from the stack profile that it is waiting on a semaphore instead. Anyone knows what's causing this hang?

Comment: I have also changed the code to use the pinned memory technique from the Nvidia SDK examples, with only one initial `clEnqueueMapBuffer` and subsequent `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` from the pinned memory. The same thing happens.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @buttifulbuttefly. How can I use ptrace to check this, any hints? I have now seen the same behaviour on the latest Nvidia drivers (from CUDA SDK) on Mac OS X, so if it's a driver thing, it should be universal.